# How do i read the contents of my firebase realtime database and retrieve them to be displayed using javascript onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, cloud

[My Databse contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyps2.png)

```
function PushDish(DishCode, DishName) {
```

Materialize.toast('Dish Added', 4000, 'rounded')
  firebase.database().ref('Table - 1/' + DishCode).set({
    DishCode: DishCode,
    DishName: DishName
  });
}

the code im currently using to push data

i would appreciate it if someone could help me write a read and display java script fucntion

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have this data in your database:

```
yourDatabase {
  lkljkj3jkl3j {
    ChildOne: childValueOne,
    ChildTwo: childValueTwo,
    ChildThree: childValueThree
  }
  lkljkfdfjkl3k {
    ChildOne: childValueOne,
    ChildTwo: childValueTwo,
    ChildThree: childValueThree
  }
}
```

Now what you want to do is loop through your data when you click a button, and display the data as well. So we'll make a function for that with jquery.

```
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
 var ref = firebase.database().ref('yourDatabase');
 ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      if(childData){
      $("#myData").html(childData);
      } else {
      $("#myData").html("There is no data");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

In our html:

```
<button id="myBtn">my button</button>
<p id="myData"></p>
```

Also if you want to read data of one child only:

```
$("#myData").html(childSnapshot.ChildOne);
```

I'd give this a read as well if I were you:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Comment: Thanks for your help , ill try and implement it and get back to you , good day :)